# Is there a JDBC 4.1 driver for DB2?

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, jcc

Does DB2 (LUW) support JDBC 4.1?

From where can I download this driver if it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The db2 driver for JDBC v3 is called db2jcc.jar

For version 4, the JDBC driver for DB2 is called db2jcc4.jar, and the documentation says: JDBC 4.0 or later functions.

Your question is specific for JDBC 4.1, however the DB2 documentation does not say anything about this JDBC specific release (RowSetProviderClass and auto-close of connection, statement an resultSet)

It does not seem that this jdbc driver is available for this jdbc release.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvintro.html

List of db2 jdbc drivers: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up answer to what @AngocA mentioned above, I developed a simple program to test the DB2 driver to check its compliance level with `JDBC`.
I found that the first DB2 driver claiming such support is driver `4.13.127`.

So any thing after that should also support `JDBC 4.1`

Here is my simple program you can use to check for the compliance level:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class tester {
    // Replace these info with your DB2 info
    private final static String hostName = "mydb2.db2.com";
    private final static String portNum = "50000";
    private final static String userName = "dasusr";
    private final static String password = "db2sdin";
    private final static String dbName = "mydb";

    private final static String fullURL = "jdbc:db2://" + hostName + ":" + portNum
                                          + "/" + dbName + ":" + "user=" + userName
                                          + ";password=" + password + ";";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(fullURL);
            DatabaseMetaData conMD = con.getMetaData();    
            String driverName = conMD.getDriverName();
            String driverVersion = conMD.getDriverVersion();
            String jdbcVersion = conMD.getJDBCMajorVersion()
                                 +"."+ conMD.getJDBCMinorVersion();
            System.out.println("driverName: " + driverName + "\n"
                                +"driverVersion: "+ driverVersion + "\n"
                                +"jdbcVersion: "+ jdbcVersion);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

In your `.classpath`  which would look like this in the `Navigator` tab in eclipse:

[image]

add the location of the driver you would like to test like this:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse
                          .jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>

    <!-- driver_4.13.127  -->
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="driver_4.13.127/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="driver_4.13.127/db2jcc4.jar"/>

    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You should then get an output similar to this:

```
driverName: IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
driverVersion: 4.13.127
jdbcVersion: 4.1
```